Accessing Outer Class Variable From Inner Class
I'm trying to set up a movelist for a game I'm creating, and attempting to do this through nested classes to avoid repeating the need to define the name of the move, without activating it immediately.
class moveset:
    def __init__(self,move_name):
        self.name = move_name
    class move:
        def use_move(self,user,target):
            user.attack(target)


move_list = [moveset("slash").move]

move_list[0].use_move(user,target)

I'm able to use the nested class without issue, however if I want to call the name of the move it appears undefined (move_list[0].name, or accessing self.name from the move class itself).
After some research I understand that nested classes are difficult in regards to accessing the outer class, however is there any way to have an initialized function for an outer class that inner classes can still access? I'm hoping to use nested classes so that I can create multiple moves and assign them elsewhere.
My apologies if anything is unclear, I'm still fairly inexperienced with Python.

An "inner class" isn't particularly meaningful in Python.  All this does is make the class harder to access, it doesn't get any special access to the containing class.

moveset("slash").move returns the move class, not an instance of the class.

You've never created an instance of the move class.

AIUI, nested classes are a useful thing in Java, but not Python.

Feels like this is a case of an XY problem. Could you describe more clearly what your actual objective is?

why nested in the first place? flat is better than nested (zen of python). Also you probbaly want instances of moveset.move in the list, not the class

My goal is to create multiple moves stored to a weapon, which can then later be called and used. My idea behind nested classes was to create multiple moves that all shared similar properties (name, damage, etc.) but different functions once executed. But I'm not sure if there's a better solution.
So for example, have a weapon class with a move_list, and then be able to easily call weapon.move_list[0] which has already been defined, and then use it if that makes sense.

Perhaps you could give some more examples of the multiple moves that you want. Its still likely that you don't need nested classes.

@quamrana I've already made a user class and a weapon class, along with different status effects and skills. My goal was to have it so that a weapon can be defined with a particular list of moves (wapon(move_list)), and that list of moves consists of either applying status effects to the user, attacking multiple times, etc. My thought process behind nested classes was to create multiple moves as objects, store them in the weapon, and then call them when the player acts. Since all moves will have a name, damage, type, etc. I went with nested classes.
weapon.move_list[0].use_move(user,target)

@Oyavo your goal doesn't seem to be anything that would be helped by nesting classes (there really is never a great reason to do this in python to begin with). So simply don't nest the classes.

all you did with this [moveset("slash").move] is put the move class in the list. If you had simply defined the class Move at the module level (as one normally would) then this would be equivalent to move_list = [Move]

"however is there any way to have an initialized function for an outer class that inner classes can still access?" there is no way to do this that would be different from the way you would do it without nesting classes, except it might be slightly wordier, since the only thing that nesting a class does is make you access it through the namespace of the enclosing class.

There are many ways to achieve your outcome, but I would have the user class execute the moves and pass information down rather than try to grab information upwards the hierarchy.
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, weapons = []):
        self.name = name
        self.weapons = weapons

    def add_weapon(self, weapon):
        self.weapons.append(weapon)

    def use_weapon_move(self, weapon, move, target):
        if weapon not in self.weapons:
            print(f'{self.name} does not have {weapon}')
            return
        if move not in weapon.moves:
            print(f'{weapon} can not perform {move}')
            return

        move.use_move(self, target)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, moves = []):
        self.name = name
        self.moves = moves

    def add_move(self, move):
        self.moves.append(move)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Move:
    def __init__(self, name, damage = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage

    def use_move(self, user, target):
        print(f'{user} deals {self.damage} to {target}')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

user = User('Bob')
target = User('Alice')
sword = Weapon('Sword')
bow = Weapon('Bow')
slash = Move('Slash', 5)
shoot = Move('Shoot', 3)

user.add_weapon(sword)
sword.add_move(slash)

user.use_weapon_move(sword, slash, target)

user.use_weapon_move(bow, slash, target)

user.use_weapon_move(sword, shoot, target)
        
        

